# How to add (not override) migrations to a third party app in Django (South)

Tags: django, django-south

I'm trying to add a `SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULE` for a third-party app (in this case django-waffle).  However, I do not want to override the migrations in django-waffle, I simply want to run **additional** migrations.  (For my particular use-case I'm trying to create datamigrations which add django-waffle flags.)

The [docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-migration-modules) and [code](https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/src/f706507cbbf42a612fc5e6b3c632980054820f7f/south/migration/base.py?at=default#cl-134) for `SOUTH_MIGRATIONS_MODULES` seem to indicate that specifying a migration module for an app will **override** the app's original migrations.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a datamigration, you can specify which apps "participate" in the datamigration with the `--freeze` command line flag. If you have a `glue` or `core` app, as I like to call them, just add your datamigration there, and specify `--freeze waffle` on the command line. You can then access the waffle models via `orm['waffle.ModelNameHere']`.

This way, you don't need to override anything. You might need to set `depends_on` to get the migration order right.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I currently do.  I have an app named `third` where I do migrations for third party apps.  However it's getting somewhat messy for my tastes as I continue to add migrations from different apps to it.  And I want to avoid adding more apps for the sole purpose of migrations.